# while executing a shell script in Unix Bash Shell, how is a file location resolved for relative paths?

Tags: bash, unix, shell

while executing a shell script in Unix Bash Shell, say any file in another folder and that is referenced by the script references some other file like ../../file_system_1/public/dir1/dir2/file2.xml

script.sh --> references dir1/file1 as "./dir1/file1"
  dir1/file1 references another file as ../../file_system_1/public/dir1/dir2/file2.xml

so relative to which file is the file2 resolved? to the script.sh location or the file1 folder location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you see, if you put an `ls` in your script.sh? That's the starting point for evaluating relative paths. Usually it's your current working directory. So to answer your question: It's probably neither script.sh's nor file1's location.

Why probably? Because it depends on what you do in your script. If you execute an `cd /home/` in script.sh, the include path changes.

Comment: You could do `pwd` instead of `ls`. The result is more concise and usable.

Comment: True. I just wanted to give an easily comprehensable example.

Answer (score 4):

Relative paths are resolved in reference to the current working directory, as given by `$(pwd)`.

Each time a resolution takes place, `$(pwd)` is evaluated. This means that the same `../myfile` path string represents a different file before and after a `cd` command in your script.

Answer (score 2):

In a shell script, `..` pathnames are always relative to the current working directory, not to any other file pathname. this is the value of `$PWD`.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you mean by "reference".

Relative paths are -- when used to access a file or directory -- interpreted relative to the current working directory of the process. The CWD is inherited across `fork()` and friends, so any sub-processes that your script executes will inherit the CWD. Interpreting relative paths is done by the C library and/or file system layer and this works the same in *all* programs that use the standard APIs, not just `bash`.

If your paths are *not* being used to access a file or folder, then they are just strings and do not "resolve" to anything.

Answer (score 1):

It's resolved relative to the current working directory. If the script doesn't change directories with `cd` or similar this is the directory in which you were when you started the script.